# Поиск подстроки в строке "от" и "до" C#

Tags: c#

Например хочу найти строку начинающую на "лала," а заканчивающуюся на "ooo."
Можно ли это как-то реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас есть строка и нужно убедиться, то она начинается на "лала" и оканчивается на "ooo", то можно написать такой код:

```
var s = "лалаыыыооо";
if (s.StartsWith("лала") && s.EndsWith("ооо"))
    Console.WriteLine("Да");
```

или с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
var s = "лалаыыыооо";
var p = "лала.*ооо";
if (Regex.IsMatch(s, p))
    Console.WriteLine("Да");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "ooo-ляляЛАЛАoooАААА";
int start = s.IndexOf("ляля");
int end = s.IndexOf("ooo", start);
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(start, end - start + "ooo".Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Лично я бы это реализовал бы через регулярные выражения.
в даном случае, если я не ошибаюсь, регулярка должна быть вот такой: `lala.*gaga`

```
 Match match = Regex.Match("asdfkj;ldjasf\r\nlalakljhsdfkjlhfgaga\r\nkldfsjljf\r\nlalagaga", @"lala.*gaga",
 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

здесь 2 строки начинаются с lala и заканчиваются gaga и обе будут найдены.

Замечу, что это работает с массивом строк, а не просто со строкой. То есть это прокатит с большими текстами. Если же нужно просто проверить конкретную строку закинувши ее в иф с условием `s.StartsWith("lala") && s.EndsWith("gaga")`